# This code is not spitting divs into two columns how can I achieve that?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

This should split the divs into columns but this isn't working not sure why?

Like col-lg-8 and col-lg-4 should have split into two for large screens.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello World</h1>
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-6 col-lg-4" style="background-color:yellow;">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
          Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-9 col-md-6 col-lg-8" style="background-color:pink;">
          Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have connected bootstrap styles and scripts incorrectly. Use bellow.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```